# Prove integral equality involving non-holomorphic function.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am given this function:

$$I_n(R,\lambda) = \int_{\gamma_R} (z^*)^n \text{e}^{\lambda z}dz$$

Where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma_R$ is the circle centered in $i\pi$ with radius $R$, $C(i\pi,R)$, with $R>0$ and $R \neq \pi$ if $n<0$.

I need to prove that:

$$I_n(R,\lambda) = \int_{\gamma_R} \Big{(}\frac{R^2}{z-i\pi}- i\pi\Big{)}^n \text{e}^{\lambda z}dz$$

But I don't know where to start. My first guess is that since the complex conjugate is nowhere differentiable, then the function inside the integral is not holomorphic and we can't use something like Cauchy´s integral formula. I have tried doing this parametrization:

$$\gamma_R = \pi \text{e}^{\frac{\pi}{2}i} + R\text{e}^{i\theta}$$
And then substituting $z = \gamma_R(\theta)$, but it is not helping. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $z$ on the circle $C(i\pi, R)$ is
$$
 R^2 = |z-i\pi|^2 = (z-i\pi) (z^* + i \pi)
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
 z^* = \frac{R^2}{z-i\pi} - i\pi \, .
$$