# How to compute integral using Cauchy's integral formula for different parameters.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to compute this:

$$I_n(R,\lambda) = \int_{\gamma_R} (z^*)^n \text{e}^{\lambda z}dz$$

(Where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma_R$ is the circle centered in $i\pi$ with radius $R$, $C(i\pi,R)$, with $R>0$ and $R \neq \pi$ if $n<0$.)

For different values of n and then particularise for different values of R. The problem I'm facing is that the way I came up with does not seem to work because I always get the same result for all cases. I thought I could multiply and divide by $z$, and then:

$$\int_{\gamma_R} (z^*)^n \text{e}^{\lambda z}dz = \int_{\gamma_R} \frac{z(z^*)^n \text{e}^{\lambda z}}{z-0}dz = \int_{\gamma_R} \frac{f(z)}{z-0}dz = 2\pi i f(0)$$

But the function $f(z)$ is always equal to zero in z=0, which does not really make any sense to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does $z^*$ mean the conjugate of $z$? If yes, the map $z\mapsto z^*$ is not holomorphic. You may need to calculate the integral using a parametrization of the path.

Comment: It does, sorry. I should clarify in the question. Could a parametrization like $\gamma_R = \pi \text{e}^{\frac{\pi}{2}i} + R\text{e}^{i\theta}$ work? In which case I guess I would need do a change of variable with $z = \gamma_R (\theta)$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Do you really need to "compute" this integral or just want to prove the statement in another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4297528/) of yours?

Comment: Both, but the other question would come in first in terms of priority. I am somewhat stuck. I will try what you mentioned.